# Execute function when enter is pressed if textbox has focus

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to execute a function by pressing the enter key on the keyboard only if a certain textbox has focus.  i.e. if any other textbox has focus or no textbox has focus, the enter key should do nothing.

Comment: Yes, by assigning an event handler to the textbox for e.g. the `keyup` event which checks whether the enter key was pressed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
$('#myTextbox').bind('keyup', function(e) {

    if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) { // 13 is enter key

        // Execute code here.

    }

});
```

Comment: what should I do if my #myTextbox id dynamic i mean to say that I m passing Id of particular post along with text box id like  #myTextbox - {{postid}} @Seth

Comment: This isn't working for me; the enter key is submitting the form which the input field resides in, instead of triggering the code.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(function(){
     $("#textarea").keyup(function(e){
          if (e.keyCode === 13) {
               //do stuff
          }
     });

});
```

Answer (score -2):

**Enter any thing in Text box then press Enter to execute**

```
 <form onSubmit='alerttest(this); return false'>        
     <input type="text">         
 </form>


 <script language="javascript">
   function alerttest()
    {
        alert("Executing jolly.exe !!!!");
        // function edited by Inderpreet singh
    }
</script>
```